# Is it possible to write vagrant config file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, vagrant

i have new Vagrantfile (generated with `init` command) with next first lines:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
```

so, the question is in title, it is possible to write/rewrite vagrant default config file in python? and how it must be look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to write Vagrant config files in Python. The native language for Vagrant is Ruby, and that's the language the config files are written in.

The [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/) explain this and point out that it's usually not a problem if you don't know Ruby:

> The syntax of Vagrantfiles is Ruby, but knowledge of the Ruby
>   programming language is not necessary to make modifications to the
>   Vagrantfile, since it is mostly simple variable assignment. In fact,
>   Ruby isn't even the most popular community Vagrant is used within,
>   which should help show you that despite not having Ruby knowledge,
>   people are very successful with Vagrant.

If you are looking to use Python for the provisioning step, you could use the [Shell provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) and write your scripts in Python.

There are also some projects that can help use Vagrant in a Python-focused environment. For example: [todddeluca/python-vagrant](https://github.com/todddeluca/python-vagrant).